# Making the resolution of Ubuntu 22.04 changeable in HyperV

Tags: ubuntu, resolution, hyper-v

I use Hyper-V to host Ubuntu 22.04 and Debian 11 Machines. I need the possibility to change the resolution **on the fly** via the display menu. Ubuntu Mate gives me this possibility right after installation without any extra steps. I really need to know what is responsible for this behavior.

What I tried:

- Installing linux-image-extra-virtual
- Editing /etc/default/grub + update-grub

Everything i find online is to change the resolution to a static one. I need to be able to change it without reconnecting or rebooting.